# Multiselect field displays 0 items instead of actual option names. Anyone fixed this?

Tags: css, mobile, multi-select

In a form on my application, I have a multiselect field section to let users select more than one option. However, on the mobile version, it displays "0 items" until clicked, where the user selects say 2 items, and then returns to say "2 items".

Anyone know how to fix this? It's not user-friendly and is annoying for styling.

```
<div class="multiselect_field">
<div><%= form_builder.label t :u_ed_degrees %></div>
    <%= form_builder.select :degrees, degrees, {}, { :multiple => true, :size => 33 } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, and perhaps CSS, we can't see what you're doing wrong, which means we can't help, or see how 'to fix this.'

Comment: I added the HTML but I don't think the CSS is the problem, as I'm not sure it directs exactly to styling, but more so to how to alter the way mobile devices handle multiselect fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as iOS doesn't support this. Maybe they will get on board like Android has soon.